# varargs in lambda functions in Python

Tags: python, lambda, variadic-functions

Is it possible a lambda function to have variable number of arguments? 
For example, I want to write a metaclass, which creates a method for every method of some other class and this newly created method returns the opposite value of the original method and has the same number of arguments.
And I want to do this with lambda function. How to pass the arguments? Is it possible?

```
class Negate(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, _dict):
        extended_dict = _dict.copy()
        for (k, v) in _dict.items():
            if hasattr(v, '__call__'):
                extended_dict["not_" + k] = lambda s, *args, **kw:  not v(s, *args, **kw)
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, extended_dict)

class P(metaclass=Negate):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def yes(self):
        return True

    def maybe(self, you_can_chose):
        return you_can_chose
```

But the result is totally wrong:

```
>>>p = P(0)
>>>p.yes()
True
>>>p.not_yes()     # should be False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#150>", line 1, in <module>
    p.not_yes()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\p.py", line 51, in <lambda>
    extended_dict["not_" + k] = lambda s, *args, **kw:  not v(s, *args, **kw)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)
>>>p.maybe(True)
True
>>>p.not_maybe(True)     #should be False
True
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no problem using varargs in lambda functions. The issue here is different:

The problem is that the the lambda refrences the loop variable `v`. But by the time the lambda is called, the value of `v` has changed and the lambda calls the wrong function. This is always something to watch out for when you define a lambda in a loop.

You can fix this by creating an additional function which will hold the value of `v` in a closure:

```
def create_not_function(v):
    return lambda s, *args, **kw:  not v(s, *args, **kw)

for (k, v) in _dict.items():
    if hasattr(v, '__call__'):
        extended_dict["not_" + k] = create_not_function(v)
```

Answer (score 38):

Yes.

```
>>> l = lambda *x: print(x)
>>> l(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Note that this will only work with Python3. This syntax isn't supported in Python2.

Comment: More precisely, `lambda *x:` will work in Python 2, but `print` inside a lambda only works in Python 3.

Comment: Note that in `print(x)`, it will print the arguments as a tuple, while `print(*x)` would call print with the arguments unpacked.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas Haferburg (@"Joe Koberg" thanks also but the "print(x) was a bit confusing, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
#lambda function with *args

l1=[1,2,3,4]
l2=(1,2,3,4)

val=lambda *args : sum(args )


val(*l1,*l2)
```

Comment: Please make the relevant difference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2914938/7733418 more obvious. Explaining how your code works and why it helps would do that.

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality), and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32196973)

Comment: This also essentially duplicates the other two answers.