# Scipy curve_fit with a parameters matrix of unknown shape

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares

I am trying to use either scipy.curve_fit or scipy.least_squares for a function like

```
def f(x, C): 
    
  r = 0
  for i in range( len(C) ) :
      for j in range( len(C[i]) ):
          r+= x[0]**j * x[1]**i * C[i][j]          
  return r
```

where `C` is a list of lists of length defined run time. One of the parameters of the code is something like `[[1., 1.]]` or `[[1., 1.], [1.]]` which defines the shape of `C`.

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136737/using-scipy-curve-fit-for-a-variable-number-of-parameters), but there the `C`  would be a NxN matrix, and `curve_fit` does not work well with matrices as input. I tried to define a function with `x, *args` as parameters but with no luck for now.

I also tried following [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335524/how-to-use-scipy-optimize-curve-fit-to-use-lists-of-variable/60409667#60409667) which uses `least_squares` directly, but also here I get the obstacle that I do not know the size of the rows beforehand.

I feel that a combination of the two answers can work for me but I cannot figure it out. I was thinking to write a function that has as parameters the length of `C`, a list of the lengths of `C[i]`, and then the elements of `C` flattened, but I cannot write a working version of the code.
If anyone has a clear understanding of how to do that, or had a similar problem, I'd be thankful for any help.

Comment: Is C always full of ones?

Comment: Not necessarily, it is the initial guess. In my code it serves to give the shape mostly, how many rows and how many columns per row

Answer (score 0):

Since this question got some recent activity I will answer it, as I solved it few days later. I solved it with a lambda function.

I defined my function as

```
def f(xy, *args, dimC = 1, dimCi = [2]): 

   x, y = xy # I have to unpack the tuple because a normal list seems to not work

   r = 0

   for i in range( dimC ) :
       for j in range( dimCi[i] ):
           r+= args[i*dimC + j] * x**i * k2**j
        
   return r
```

Then I just need to flatten the initial guess and I am free to call

```
C, cov_C = curve_fit(lambda x, *p: f(x, *p, dimC = dimMat, dimCi = dimMati), ( x, y ), z), p0=init_guess)
```

Comment: We don't have `dimMat` or `dimMati`, among other things; so this answer is not reproducible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Reinderien Just read the question and then the answer. The entire point is that you have a list of lists of unequal length that has to be defined at runtime. dimMat and dimMati are the number of rows and the columns per each rows (which, in general, varies). Of course you need to adapt it to your code. This is clear if you compare f in the answer with f in the question.