# curve_fit with polynomials of variable length

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm new to python (and programming in general) and want to make a polynomial fit using `curve_fit`, where the order of the polynomials (or the number of fit parameters) is variable.

I made this code which is working for a fixed number of 3 parameters `a,b,c`

```
# fit function
def fit_func(x, a,b,c):
    p = np.polyval([a,b,c], x)
    return p

# do the fitting
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_func, x_data, y_data)
```

But now I'd like to have my fit function to only depend on a number `N` of parameters instead of `a,b,c,...`.

I'm guessing that's not a very hard thing to do, but because of my limited knowledge I can't get it work.

I've already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136737/using-scipy-curve-fit-for-a-variable-number-of-parameters), but I wasn't able to apply it to my problem.

Comment: I recommend looking at the numpy documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html which has example code at the bottom of the page.

Comment: But that's the documentation for `polyfit`. I need to use `curve_fit` because I have to expand the code for other types of functions later on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define the function to be fit to your data like this:

```
def fit_func(x, *coeffs):
    y = np.polyval(coeffs, x)
    return y
```

Then, when you call `curve_fit`, set the argument `p0` to the initial guess of the polynomial coefficients.  For example, this plot is generated by the script that follows.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Generate a sample input dataset for the demonstration.
x = np.arange(12)
y = np.cos(0.4*x)


def fit_func(x, *coeffs):
    y = np.polyval(coeffs, x)
    return y


fit_results = []
for n in range(2, 6):
    # The initial guess of the parameters to be found by curve_fit.
    # Warning: in general, an array of ones might not be a good enough
    # guess for `curve_fit`, but in this example, it works.
    p0 = np.ones(n)

    popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_func, x, y, p0=p0)
    # XXX Should check pcov here, but in this example, curve_fit converges.

    fit_results.append(popt)


plt.plot(x, y, 'k.', label='data')

xx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
for p in fit_results:
    yy = fit_func(xx, *p)
    plt.plot(xx, yy, alpha=0.6, label='n = %d' % len(p))

plt.legend(framealpha=1, shadow=True)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of polyval specify p is an array of coefficients from the highest to lowest. With x being a number or array of numbers to evaluate the polynomial at. It says, the following.

> If p is of length N, this function returns the value:
>
> p[0]*x**(N-1) + p[1]*x**(N-2) + ... + p[N-2]*x + p[N-1]

```
def fit_func(p,x):
    z = np.polyval(p,x)
    return z
```

e.g.

```
t= np.array([3,4,5,3])
y = fit_func(t,5)
503
```

which is if you do the math here is right.