# Multivariate lambda function in Python that scales with number of input variables received

Tags: python, function, lambda, dimensions

The following toy function ordinarily takes two input variables:

```
f = lambda u1, u2 : (u1*u2)*(u1**2+u2**2)
```

but can scale beyond the bivariate case to higher dimensions:

```
if dim == 2:
    f = lambda u1, u2 : (u1*u2)*(u1**2+u2**2)
if dim == 3:
    f = lambda u1, u2, u3 : (u1*u2*u3)*(u1**2+u2**2+u3**2)
if dim == 4:
    f = lambda u1, u2, u3, u4 : (u1*u2*u3*u4)*(u1**2+u2**2+u3**2+u4**2)
```

How can the lambda function be written so that it can expand itself in the call `lambda u1, u2, u3, u4, ...`  as well as the function body itself, based on number of inputs sent to it, similar to how a defined function can be declared as `def f(*args)` where `*args` is an arbitrary number of input arguments?

Comment: You mean ``lambda *args: ...``? Since you already seem to know how this works for ``def`` function literals, why use a ``lambda`` at all?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914883/varargs-in-lambda-functions-in-python?

Comment: ok the call `lambda *args:` makes sense, but how can the function body also scale with the number of arguments if the function body follows a mathematical structure as shown?

Comment: Your formula is the product of the terms divided by the sum of the squares. Can you not code that up as a function already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`lambda` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) supports the same parameter list syntax as the [`def` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function), including variadic positional and keyword argument.

```py
f = lambda *us: math.prod(us) * sum(u**2 for u in us)
```

If the `*us` are not invariant when multiplied by `1` or added to `0`, the `*` and `+` operations can be applied across elements via [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator

f = lambda *us: reduce(operator.mul, us) * reduce(operator.add, (u**2 for u in us))
```

Comment: why does `sum` enclose a for loop but `math.prod` doesn't? and does this change using `numpy.prod` and `numpy.sum`?

Comment: Because each element in the product is taken as-is, while each element in the sum needs to be squared. Note that ``u**2 for u in us`` inside the ``sum(...)`` is a *generator expression* which produces an iterable – both ``sum`` and ``prod`` internally iterate over their argument.

Comment: is it ok to use `numpy` for both instead

Comment: @develarist I have added a version that should work with any type that worked with the functions shown in the question. That includes ``numpy.array``, for example.

Comment: @develarist I just realised that ``*1`` and ``+0`` are perfectly fine for ``numpy``. The initial version using ``math.prod`` and ``sum`` should work fine for you – please test it. You can however also use ``numpy.prod`` and ``numpy.sum``.

Comment: If it's the `numpy`'s, then they would both need a for loop?

Comment: @develarist The ``for`` has nothing to do with ``numpy``; if my initial comment was not sufficient explanation, further comments are not suitable to teach the background of this. Please just verify that the given code works for you.

Comment: sorry didn't mean to add on more work, was only curious. i have moved on to another step, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689891/how-to-change-support-of-multivariate-integral-to-0-1k-using-scipy-integrate